# Why are embedded reports not loading after longer period of being logged in?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-embedded

I'm working on an ASP.NET MVC application that is using PowerBI Embedded to display some reports. I started with the application from the tutorial and have not made any changes to the code rendering the report. I did, however, update all the nuget packages to the latest versions.

In general, the app works fine and reports are being rendered correctly. However, sometimes I run into a problem where all the reports stop loading and I only get a flashing Power BI logo.

If I open a new browser session in incognito mode and log in on the same user it all works fine again. However, in the original tab it doesn't work until I close everything or reset the cache.

I noticed that it always happens after I am logged in for a longer period of time (30-60 minutes maybe). My best guess was that there's something wrong with the tokens, but I am not able to track it down.

Any hints what might be causing it?

UPDATE:
I just noticed that after longer period of time the logo stops flashing and I get an error "This content isn't available". When I look into the browser console I get this:

```
wabi-west-europe-b-primary-redirect.analysis.windows.net/explore/reports/fcbf92f1-f8d7-4c61-aeb3-06f195835413/modelsAndExploration?preferReadOnlySession=true:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_SPDY_PROTOCOL_ERROR
reportEmbed.min.js:1 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Object: {"message":"LoadReportFailed","detailedMessage":"Get report failed","level":6,"technicalDetails":{"requestId":"6d99f480-0f1c-47d0-9598-cab569018dd0"}}
    at A (reportEmbed.min.js:1)
    at A (reportEmbed.min.js:1)
    at reportEmbed.min.js:1
    at e.invokeTask (reportEmbed.min.js:1)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (reportEmbed.min.js:1)
    at e.invokeTask (reportEmbed.min.js:1)
    at t.runTask (reportEmbed.min.js:1)
    at g (reportEmbed.min.js:1)
    at t.invokeTask (reportEmbed.min.js:1)
    at i.useG.invoke (reportEmbed.min.js:1)
Ye @ reportEmbed.min.js:1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was, as [EttoreP](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1844568/ettorep) correctly pointed, casued by an expired token. However, the main culprit was caching. My App is not a Single Page Application, so the token should be acquired with every page load. It appeared that the results were cached for longer than the expiration time of the token. After running the page again after an hour it was using the cached token and causing errors. Adding an OutputCache attribute to the controller solved the problem. Thanks for the help and good hints!

```
 [OutputCache(NoStore = true, Duration = 0)]
```

Answer (score 2):

This happens because the *embedToken* you use for retrive the dashboard from the powerBi rest api expires after approx 1 hour.
You have to refresh the token with a new one before the token expires, and this is not automatically handled from the Microsoft api (as far as i know).
You have to use the *authentication token* previously obtained and requets a new *embedToken*.
Consider that also the *authentication token* expires after some time, if this happens you have to obtain a new one before the request of the new *embed token*.
You can do this re-logging with user/pass or, a better solution, using the *refresh token* that the api gives you when you authenticate (when autenticated you retrive an *auth token* and a *refresh token* you can use for request a fresh *auth token* without logging again with user-pass).
[Some azure documentation here](https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/azure/active-directory/develop/v1-protocols-oauth-code) about the authentication for use an azure resource.
**Update**:
Consider also that in the object *embedToken* you obtain there is the *expiration date* you can use for refresh the token before it expires, [here some docs from azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/rest/api/power-bi/embedtoken/reports_generatetokeningroup#embedtoken)

Comment: Thanks for the hint. This was also my way of thinking but... It is a standard MVC application, not a single page app. I am not very experienced with web development, but my understanding is that whenever I refresh the page it should hit the controller again and run the whole code. In other words, it should get a new token every single time I reload. Or am I mistaken?

Comment: @JakubKrupa maybe that when you hit the refresh button the browser uses the cached version of the page instead downloading a new one, so the routine for generate the token is skipped somehow...if i remember well you can try to force a "true" reload of the page holding _ctrl_ + reload in chrome...

Comment: This seems not to be the case. I checked it and I am getting a new token every time i refresh the page. Funny thing is that when it stops working after about an hour, it again starts working after some time.

Comment: @JakubKrupa so you are printing on screen the token you are using, and when an hour passes and the report stops working you refresh the page, the token changes but the report still does not work?

Comment: Well, I am printing the token on the screen and I can see that it gets updated every single time I refresh. However, an hour has passed and the reports are still working.
Two ideas I have now:
a) Problem lies somewhere else
b) It may be a caching problem? Maybe by adding some dynamic content the browser stopped caching the site?

Comment: @JakubKrupa what do you mean with "an hour has passed and the reports are still working"? The issue is now resolved by itself or refreshing resolves the issue? And also "Maybe by adding some dynamic content the browser stopped caching the site" means you have modifyed something? Try to be more precise in what you have changed (if you have), what's the new behaviour of the page (if there is) and post some code you are using. Anyway if refreshing the page the token changes, the browser should load the report correctly.

Comment: Sorry for that, I'll try to be more precise. I wanted to see how tokens are behaving so I simply printed the tokenId and expiration date over the report. What I noticed is that since I did that, I am no longer able to reproduce the error. Previously, after about an hour of being logged in, the reports stopped working. With the token id and expiry date printed on the screen, everything works fine even after the initial token expired - it just gets a new one. Hence my suspicion, that it was a caching problem and printing something new on screen (token) caused the browser to no longer cache it.

Comment: @JakubKrupa basically printing the token on page resolves totally the issue and the reports now works without stopping (so the token is automatically updated by the api before expiring and not need a reload of the page)?

Answer (score -1):

This happens because your of your implementation, a good ETL can be resolve your problem, but check your connection and the cache timeout implementation.

Comment: What do you mean a good ETL? It has nothing to do with the report or the data loading process. It is only a matter of PowerBI embedded. After some period of time all reports stop loading no matter how simple they are. They all work fine in the Power BI web and desktop client.

Comment: I know, but how are implemented? This is a trouble. A bad ETL impact in your process.